# SolrCloud index empty after a successful document submission

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I've SolrCloud (5.1.0) and ZooKeeper (3.4.6) running on 3 servers. I've a single collection, consisting of 3 shards. I've defined a schema (schema.xml) and all 3 Solr servers and ZooKeeper servers are up and running. Now I'd like to add a documents to the collection (my index). In the Solr admin site ( http://MYIP:8983/solr/#/ ), using the Core Selector, I select a core to work on. I click on "Documents" and select "XML" for "Document Type". I paste my XML and click on the submit button.

[image]

I get a "success" status back.

[image]

When I query everything in my index, I see that nothing has been added to my index (numfound = 0).

[image]

How come my index is empty?

Comment: When I choose "JSON" for the "Document Type" and paste my data in JSON format then the document is added to the index.

Comment: Can u check the "logging" tab and see if u get any errors? Can you post your entire xml file also? May be the XML is not in correct format?

Comment: The logging doesn't show anything unusual  besides the well-known errors about missing admin pages (admin-extra.html, admin-extra.menu-top.html, etc.). The first screenshot almost show the complete XML. There is one more field and closing tags for doc and add. The XML has been verified. I've decided to use JSON instead of XML.